# Oops! Something Bad Happened! when searching the help

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, help-center

Go to: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Search for: `[tag]` *(actually any string within brackets)*

Result:
[image]

Comment: It is logged, they are aware of it.  Big changes to search, tested in production as usual.

Comment: Great error page, great way of getting to know employees

Comment: Quite a lot of search bugs at the moment. Hurry up unicorn `:-)`

Comment: Actually looks like it happens even by simply searching for `[` or `{` or `^`. I think the rule is "wildcards characters", though I'm not sure what is the whole list.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: I wonder how many records have been recorded by now.

Comment: Why does it say to leave feedback at meta? Only registered users with 5 rep can use meta. Is additional information not wanted from the great, unwashed masses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been poking around the search code we used prior to our recent refactor and searches containing anything not directly supported by Lucene (including square brackets, braces, tildes, etc.) have *never* worked for the Help Centre.

We've pushed a fix to production that addresses the issue although it effectively disregards the brackets and searches for the containing text rather than the tag search you might be expecting. We don't extract tags from help centre posts so doing an actual tag search is not possible right now.